# Linux agent is sending an hardstatus in the beginning of 'echo' output

Tags: linux, echo, screen, tmux, xterm

In a program for Linux, I use this script (with root execution) to get last logged user and its locale:

```
LAST_USER=`last -1 | cut -f 1 -d " " | head -n 1`
LAST_LOCALE=`su - "$LAST_USER" -c 'echo "$LANG"'`
```

But one of the Linux agent using this script adds an hardstatus (eg. "\033];hostname\033\") in the beginning of $LAST_LOCALE and I can't figure out why.

I tried to reproduce this issue on a local Linux without success ; I tried to ask the user to do the command without the '-' option of su, without changes. Replacing 'echo' by 'printf' seems to remove the hardstatus though, so the issue seems to be linked with 'echo' itself.

I couldn't find any similar behavior with a lots of internet researching…

Note: the user is using tmux.

Comment: With `su - ...` you start a login shell for the specified user. The user may have settings in the shell's startup files that produce output or functions or aliases that change the behavior of the `echo` command. Please show the output of `su - "$LAST_USER" -c 'true' |od -tx1 -c`. If you use `su` without `-`, you will not have the user's environment which might result in a wrong `LANG` variable. Please [edit] your question and explain what problem you want to solve with this script. Why do you need the initial value of the `LANG` variable of the user who logged in last?

Comment: All good comments above. I'll add that `\033]` is almost always an indication of ANSI control characters used to manipulate the screem output, most often  for the cmd-line Prompt Value. (How to fix it? Would have to be there to experiment). Sorry! And Good luck.!

Comment: Check for `\\[\\e]` (this is the same as `\033]`) in the output of `export | grep PS` on the problem machine. This is likely where your bad strrings are coming from. How to fix??? (-??? Again, would have to be there. Good luck.